# Tfs_Configuration detail for Team Project Collection Name

Tags: c#, tfs

When I tried to attach my tfs databases using TFS console,database name is  not displaying.

According to the Microsoft description I think "Tfs_Configuration" table contains name and location of other databases.

Can any one please tell me the table name which store the the Team project collection name in the `Tfs_Configuration databases`?

Thanks

Roshil

Comment: Was the database properly detached from the source server? Or are you trying to attach a backup from an active TFS Project Collection?

Comment: Can you describe the process you've followed to be where you are now? And can you add a screenshot of what you see and describe exactly what you expect to be different in that screen?

Comment: Actaully My Db was crashed and DB has lot of Duplicate values.So i have removed the Duplicates and tried to attach again.

Comment: **!!! You should restore to a known good state as soon as possible !!!** You should have restored all databases to a previous point in time (if need be on a different environment). Just restoring a single project collection to a previous point in time is not recommended. Plus, by manually updating the tables, you've potentially left a lot of data in the system that is now unreferenced, making the structure incomplete and possibly unstable and surely unsupported. **!!! You should restore to a known good state as soon as possible !!!**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ### **WARNING**
>
> Changing anything directly in the `TFS_Configuration` and/or `TFS_*Collection` databases puts your TFS instance in an officially unsupported state and can cause all kinds of very hard to detect issues that may only surface themselves for very specific features of the product, or when it's time to install the next Update or upgrade ti the next major version.

I suspect the information you're after is is not going to be in there until you did a successful attach. You might be in a chicken/egg situation with regards to the collection showing up in the TFS_Configuration database.

The Collection DB should be listed in `TFS_Configuration\tbl_Database` and the Team Project Collection Name is stored in `tbl_CatalogResource`.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response.but I am using TFS 2010 and I cant able to see tbl_Database in the TFS_Configuration database.

Comment: Currently don't have a TFS 2010 database at hand to check. But you're going in completely the wrong direction in trying to patch up the databases manually. I hope you have good frequent backups available which you can revert to. If need be open a support case with Microsoft to get you back into a supported state.

Comment: Support available here: https://support2.microsoft.com/oas/default.aspx?gprid=15011&st=1&wfxredirect=1&sd=msdn